# How would i know if parallel running of stored proc is much efficient?

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, oracle10g

I'm using dbms_jobs to run stored procecures in parallel.

Besides from comparing the run time of each procedures against running it in parallel, 
whats the other way to know if parallel run of procedures is faster/efficient?

Is there anyway to see the CPU / usage in oracle?

Comment: DBMS_Scheduler is a better choice for running jobs in parallel, as you can define scheduler chains to do it for you without manually synchronising the jobs.

Comment: our dba did not grant me privilege on dbms_scheduler yet that's why i'm using dbms_jobs for the mean time. once granted, would surely use dbms_scheduler as i learned it has more features and easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy question to answer as most of the analysis is in the exact nature of the jobs and everything else running on the system.

Key questions to ask would be:

- Does the system have enough free resource to run jobs in parallel at the time I want to do it?
- Is there anything in the code to indicate that the jobs might benefit from running at the same time, or vice versa?

As an example of the latter, if you had multiple jobs that all required a full table scan of a very large table then you can get a benefit from running them all at the same time because they can read the same blocks from the instance buffer. Effectively, one session will read the blocks and the others will wait on them to be read. When they are run at different times they might all have to incur physical i/o to read the blocks from disc.

Notes on full tables scan: Blocks from a full table scan are loaded to the db block buffers for conventional reads (unless specified otherwise through enabling serial direct path reads in 10g) or into PGA for parallel query (unless hinted otherwise with CACHE) or serial direct path reads in 11g. When loaded to db block buffers they are not marked as MRU, as is the case with individual block reads, but "into the middle of the LRU list" according to 11.2 documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/memory.htm#CNCPT1224

In any case, the blocks do not have to be kept in memory very long at all as there would be one or more sessions registering their interest in reading them -- a high number of "buffer busy wait" would be the sign that multiple sessions are waiting for another to read the block that they're interested in.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your example. When doing a FTS, blocks are not kept in memory. Therefore, would you have an example?

Comment: @Plouf -- not the case for most FTS. See notes in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree and I still consider that as pure luck. Since the buffer cache gets its block ejected at the pace of 125MB/s (say for a poor connectivity like one hard drive full sequential, or a NAS/SAN at 1Gb/s), the FTS from differents jobs have more chances to be slighlty not synchronised, hammering the drives very much. Of course, you could put jobs to work on different partitions, in which case I definetly join you. :) This is something I tried during some performance test, 4jobs doing the same FTS, but 5s difference at launch time: no real increase.

Comment: What is it that you disagree with? The description of FTS aging?

If your storage subsystem is fast enough to age data out of the buffer cache before the next session starts reading the data segment then you either have a very small buffer cache or your storage subsystem is so fast that you don't need the buffer cache. For your example of 125MB/s, what size of buffer cache are you talking about? It would take a couple of seconds to age the blocks out of a 2GB cache, which is very small by today's standards.

Comment: Not the description, the speed of aging out data. If you have a low reading speed, you usually have a low size for the cache also. On the other hand, say you got your 128GB cache, half of it the buffer cache, and it goes in the middle of the LRU so more or less 32GB available for caching the FTS. This machine would be on a 10Gb link, reading 1,25GB/s. You need to have all your FTS within a 30s timeframe. I don't say it's impossible, just I don't consider it as very reliable. And, if you are not synchronized, the poor disks will have to go back and forth reading the same data again. My 2 cents

Comment: But maybe you do that, and it works much better than what I managed to do. In which case, congratulation! If you got some tips on how to do it properly, I take that information

Comment: The key to it is the synchronisation of the session starts of course -- using DBMS_Scheduler is a great help as a scheduler chain will kick off multiple tasks within fractions of a second of each other. My experience of Oracle systems, particularly data warehouses, has been that they are very under-specified in read rate compared to memory size and CPU.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only if queries have the same plan. (At least until some kind of shared batch scheduling gets implemented)

Comment: Yes indeed, or at least if the same large table is the first to be accessed, that sort of thing.